# Large text database: Convert to SQL or use as is

Tags: python, sql, database, text

My python project involves an externally provided database: A text file of approximately 100K lines.

This file will be updated daily.

Should I load it into an SQL database, and deal with the `diff` daily? Or is there an effective way to "query" this text file?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

- Each "entry", or line, contains three fields - any one of which can be used as an index.
- The update is is the form of the entire database - I would have to manually generate a diff
- The queries are just looking up records and displaying the text.
- Querying the database will be a fundamental task of the application.

Comment: Some questions [1] is it a differential update, or will you get the entire file at each update cycle and you have to decide which rows are updated? [2] what kind of queries do you need to do? Calculations, or just displaying the records? Answering these will help in deciding the optimum approach.

Answer (score 1):

How often will the data be queried? On the one extreme, if once per day, you might use a sequential search more efficiently than maintaining a database or index.

For more queries and a daily update, you could build and maintain your own index for more efficient queries. Most likely, it would be worth a negligible (if any) sacrifice in speed to use an SQL database (or other database, depending on your needs) in return for simpler and more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is create SQLite databases from txt files which were created from database extracts, one SQLite db for each day.

One can query across SQLite db to check the values etc and create additional tables of data.

I added an additional column of data that was the SHA1 of the text line so that I could easily identify lines that were different.

It worked in my situation and hopefully may form the barest sniff of an acorn of an idea for you.